# Javascript not loading in when importing other script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript file I've linked to an html file. The file links fine whenever I don't have anything imported into it, but whenever I import another file into it, it isn't even loaded.

What the JavaScript file looks like when it loads in.
[image: Example of script loading in.]

```
//import './the_story/project.js';

function savE(){
    alert("Saved!");
}

function loaD(){
    alert("Loaded!")
}
```

What the JavaScript file looks like when it doesn't load in.
[image: Example of the script not loading in.]

```
import './the_story/project.js';

function savE(){
    alert("Saved!");
}

function loaD(){
    alert("Loaded!")
}
```

I'm honestly pretty stumped on this. I've tried having the script inside the html file itself and it still didn't work. It claimed my functions were undefined.

Comment: Any console errors? Where are you calling the functions?

Comment: the import statement is JSM code, it doesn't work on pure JS, so are you telling the page you are using modules? <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>

Comment: @isherwood The only error I'm getting is the Electron Security Warning, but I do get this error when trying to open the html in my browser: `Access to script at 'script name' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted.`

Answer (score 0):

In your html import your javascript file as `module` like so

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

for futher reading about normal script file and module please read [official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: Having it linked as a module or not doesn't change the results.

Comment: does your console have any errors?

Comment: The only error I'm getting is the Electron Security Warning, but I do get this error when trying to open the html in my browser: `Access to script at 'script name' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted. `